# Java Convert Int to Hex and stick it in byte array element

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte

I've started learning a little java, and am trying to accomplish what is likely a very simply task but I'm struggling with it.

Say I have a byte array:

```
byte[] test = {(byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x0b};
```

and I want to change test[3], the last value which is currently the number 11 (0b), to something random.

```
Random generator = new Random();

int newTest3 = generator.nextInt(255);
```

So, now I have some random number in newTest3. I want to convert this to hex (FF) and then place that into the last element of test, or test[3].

I couldn't find much to help me on this, and I literally just picked up java a couple hours ago, so any help would be outstanding!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Converting Int to hex doesn't have any sens. Hex, Decimal and binary are representation of int. You can't store a hex value. Byte despite the name is just a number between -128, 127.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you go over so much trouble.
Use explicit cast as you are already doing :)
when you write:

```
byte[] test = {(byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x0b};
```

0x0a is actually an int which you explicitly cast to a byte. You could do the same with newTest3.

```
test[3] = (byte)  newTest3;
```

Notice that this kind of cast usually involve loss of data since byte is just 8bits and int is 32bits. so for example (FFFFFFFF would be cast to FF).

Comment: Since he's using `Random.nextInt(int)` the output of the call is guaranteed to be from `0` to `255`, so there's nothing being lost.

Comment: Taking what Quantum just said into account, that makes the answer perfect! Thanks much to both of you, as well as the other answer givers on here :)

Comment: @QuantumMechanic to avoid data loss, he should use 'generator.nextInt(255)-128;' Don't forget that byte is a signed 8bit number

Comment: He won't lose any info.  Remember than signed vs. unsigned is only in how you interpret the bit pattern, not in the bit pattern itself. If you have `byte b1 = (byte) -1;` and `byte b2 = (byte) 255` you will find out that `(b1 == b2)` is `true`.

Comment: There is dataloss if you map 255 to -1 :) Unless that's what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a byte buffer

```
// elsewhere
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

byte[] arr = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr);
buf.putInt(generator.nextInt(255);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `buf.put((byte)generator.nextInt(255));` ?

Comment: Hey! I gave that one a little test try and ran into a bit of a problem: it said "cannot find symbol" for the buf.write method. Any suggestions?

Comment: @david That would be converting byte to a byte array, not an int to a byte array.

Comment: @GGati My apologies - I wrote a class recently that used write instead of put that I've been using. The proper method is "put int". But note that this will use 4 bytes per int (because an int has 4 bytes). IF you want just 1 byte per 'int', then this isn't the proper choice.